# SELECT rows with MAX(column value) with corresponding time, DISTINCT by name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the max value with its corresponding time happened and hour, DISTINCT by its name

My time is str data type. Do we use self inner join here in order to do so?

My table is:

```
name    high             time                
-------|-----|---------------------------
name 1 | 12  | 2020-05-25 12:01:00-04:00 
name 1 | 14  | 2020-05-25 12:02:00-04:00
name 1 | 16  | 2020-05-25 12:03:00-04:00
name 2 | 12  | 2020-05-25 12:01:00-04:00 
name 2 | 11  | 2020-05-25 12:02:00-04:00
name 2 | 10  | 2020-05-25 12:03:00-04:00
name 3 | 21  | 2020-05-25 12:01:00-04:00 
name 3 | 23  | 2020-05-25 12:02:00-04:00 
name 3 | 22  | 2020-05-25 12:03:00-04:00
```

The result I would like to have is

```
  name   hour            datetime           max_high
--------|-----|---------------------------|--------
 name 1 | 12  | 2020-05-25 12:03:00-04:00 | 16   
 name 2 | 12  | 2020-05-25 12:01:00-04:00 | 12
 name 3 | 12  | 2020-05-25 12:02:00-04:00 | 23
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Why is your time a string data type? Thats just causing problems for yourself. Use the correct datatype and your life will be easier.

Comment: The python code collected the data as str(index) and loaded in the SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` would be one way to go here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTTITON BY name ORDER BY high DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    name,
    HOUR(CAST(datetime AS timestamp)) AS hour,
    datetime,
    high AS max_high
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: What does rn mean?

Comment: @EzrealReal `rn` is the column name.